# Two lightbox galleries in same webpage: one works correctly, another doesn't

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, lightbox

I have two galleries in lightbox with carousel element like this:

first script:

```
first gallery script
.....
sending to html id of gallery
```

second script:

```
second gallery script
.....
sending to html id of gallery
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) stuff
....
```

So, problem is this: when next or prev button clicked, the second gallery begins to move automatically like it pressed all time. I guess that something makes button clicked in definite intervals. What's your thoughts about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question, what I could figure the error is the name of html 'ID'. Check that ID for both the galleries is different.

If you have ID name of gallery one same as gallery two, it behaves particularly the way you have specified here. If so, change the gallery name of second carousel and create js function for second carousel in the javascript file. Hope this helps.